# Threading not working - main window freezes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have similar problem as described here:
[Threading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353923/threading-not-working)

I tried solution with passing arg =(None, ), but this gives me a traceback:

This allows me to perform downloading, but main window freezes:

```py
    def _Downloader(self):

        self.processaa = threading.Thread(target = (dbimp.FDown._FUpdate(self)))
        self.processaa.start()
```

As described under the link, I should pass arguments separately:

```py
    def _Downloader(self):

        self.processaa = threading.Thread(target = (dbimp.FDown._FUpdate), args=(None,))
        self.processaa.start()
```

But I receive following trackback:

```
H:\pyt\tool>crap.py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "H:\pyt\tool\dbimp.py", line 327, in _FUpdate
    self.file_names_update = ("MASTER", "RESERVED", "DEREG", "ACFTREF")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_names_update'
```

The function works ok without threading.

Comment: It should be `(target=dbimp.FDown._FUpdate, args=(None,))` instead of `(target = (dbimp.FDown._FUpdate), args=(None,))`. Perhaps you can run with this fixed first and see if any other error comes up.

Comment: @HenryYik , unfortunately it does not solve the problem, same error appeared.

Comment: why do you use `None` as argument ? There is no `None.file_names_update`. It seem you should use `self`  - `args=(self,)`.

Comment: Thank you, furas. That makes sense. Previously I also tried with self, but I forgot about the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Per furas' comment, it should look like this:

```
 def _Downloader(self):

        self.processaa = threading.Thread(target = (dbimp.FDown._FUpdate), args=(self,))
        self.processaa.start()
```

and threading works fine.